# Namespacing modules in the library parameter by adding js snippet... is this going to cause unforeseen problems?

Tags: webpack

I want to export multiple entry points but have them all namespaced under a common. It seems that I can accomplish this by doing this:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        SelfService: './AppCenter/SelfService',
        Admin: './AppCenter/Admin'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts/build'),
        filename: 'AppCenter.[name].js',
        library: 'AppCenter = AppCenter || {}; AppCenter.[name]'
    },
    // ...
}
```

This gives me an output file that looks like:

```js
var AppCenter = AppCenter || {}; AppCenter.Admin =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
```

which accomplishes what I want, but I'm concerned about this trickery causing other problems with webpack functionality that I haven't run into yet. Is there anything problematic with this approach?